# Laravel 5 database relationship accessing a data on another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this kind of database design

```
user_classes
- id
- user_id
- class_schedule_id

class_schedules
- id
- class_id
- date

classes
- id
- name
```

I am now in my `UserClass.php` Model File

```
public function classSchedule() {
   return $this->belongsTo('\App\ClassSchedule');
}

public static function getClassByUser($user_id){
  $user_class = self::where('user_id','=',$user_id)->with('classSchedule');
  //other codes here...
}
```

My question here is that how can I access the name of the class in the `class` table since the `user_classes` table doesn't have a direct access to the class instead it should go through first to the `class_schedule`s table.

I am not sure what `Eloquent ORM Relationship` should I use.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to rename the third class, from class to something else. Then try this,

```
class user_classes Extends Eloquent {

        function classSchedule() {
            return $this->hasMany('Class_schedules','class_schedule_id'); 
        }

    }

    class class_schedules Extends Eloquent {

        function userClasses() {
            return $this->belongsTo('user_classes', 'class_schedule_id');
        }

        function classSomething() {
            return $this->hasOne('class_something','id');
        }

    }

    class class_something Extends Eloquent {

       function classSchedules() {
           return $this->belongsTo('class_schedules', 'id');
       }
    }
```

Comment: oh right. that should be classes. That's just a typo. Let me edit it. :)

Comment: How can I include that one on my `with('classSchedule');` ?

Comment: Try it with $user_classes->with('class_schedule.class_something')->find()

Answer (score 0):

Try and follow the naming conventions within Laravel, that will make your life easier down the road.
It uses the snake_cased version of the plural of your model name to define the table name automagically.
Besides that, when you have a relation with single or plural output, name your relation methods accordingly to describe what they do and what kind of output you can expect.

I prefer a dir `/app/Models` for the models, hence the namespace, you can change this to `/app` if that's where your models are.

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserClass extends Model
{
    // only defined because laravel auto generates alphabetically
    protected $table = 'user_classes';

    public function user()
    {
        // given that User model was moved to app/Models, if not, use \App\User
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }

    public function classSchedule()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\ClassSchedule');
    }
}



<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ClassSchedule extends Model
{
    public function class()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Class');
    }
}



<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Class extends Model
{
    public function classSchedules()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ClassSchedule');
    }
}
```

Now you can basically fetch all entries of UserClass for a particular user, with or without eager loading...

```
$userClasses = UserClass::where('user_id', $userId)->get();

$userClasses->map(function($userClass) {
    echo $userClass->classSchedule->class;
});
```

More preferably you'll have a method userClasses() with a hasMany relation in your user model